# Nexmo SMS is not receiving in PHP

Tags: php, vonage

I am using NEXMO API for integrating SMS functionality for my stuff. 
    However I am getting the error as "Unroutable message - rejected"
    I don't understand what's wrong with my source code.
    Actually I want to send SMS on Indian as well as Nigerian numbers, and I would like to mention that both numbers are free of DND service.
    Do you have any idea guys which the primary setting is need to do for sending SMS.
    [Currently I have created a test account on NEXMO].Is their any limitations while using test account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help others if they stumble upon this problem...

If you are using a trial account, you must add test account phone numbers using the API dashboard:

API Settings -> Edit -> Add Number (bottom of page)

Cheers